# Using an include file from a different module

Tags: 7, .info

I've got a module that I've created just for the sole purpose of sharing .inc files between multiple modules. The modules .module file is empty, as it doesn't do anything. But in the modules .info file I have included:

```
files[] = includes\Permissions.inc
files[] = includes\Roles.inc
files[] = includes\PermissionsInterface.inc
files[] = includes\RolesInterface.inc
```

And then in a module that is using these files (a different module), I have included:

```
use Portal\Permissions;
use Portal\Roles;

$permissions = new Permissions\Permissions();
$roles = new Roles\Roles();
```

I don't have any include or require statements, because I thought that was covered by the files[] declaration in the shared modules .info file.

However, I'm getting a PHP error that it can't find the class Permissions(). Just wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this running on a Windows machine? Im wondering why you use backslashes in your paths, or if that's even valid for a Windows machine (I've never tried it with Drupal). BTW you can remove the `use` statements as D7's autoloading is not namespace-aware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `files[] =` declarations are only for classes you want to reference at runtime. The declaration should be in the module using the classes (not some other module).

If that doesnt work, look at the [xautoload](https://drupal.org/project/xautoload) module for D7. Or, simply put `include 'includes/Permissions.inc';` into the top your custom module file using those classes/functions -- if you use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features), that's what features (for D7) does; adds an include for `features.inc`.

Comment: This partially worked. I fixed the problem by creating require_once statements inside the module that was sharing out the files.